Need to segment each number from the image separately
I have created a CNN model using the MNIST dataset. I want to make predictions for the sequence of numbers present in the images. The technique involves segmenting each image and feeding it into the model, but I am facing difficulties in segmenting numbers from the images because there are two different types of images present. I need a robust technique that removes all the noise and shadows present in the images and segments each number separately.
I am sharing the images here as well.
I am looking for the robust technique and the code.





UPDATED QUESTION
Main Goal of segmentation
I am looking for a method that segments or separates each number from the images above. I believe there must be a unique or robust approach that I could use for all kinds of images (given above). I could apply separate methods for binary and color images, but I want to learn a single approach that works for images like the above.

wrong approach. let the model handle that. train the CNN to handle grayscale inputs. extend it to give you a "digitness" score for the input. then run it on the entire input as a fully convolutional network. now you have a heatmap of digitness. yes, the network will have to have a sufficiently large receptive field and it's got to be able to handle multiple scales (convolution, pooling)

Can't you just threshold on the very dark letters (which seem to be darker than anything else) using cv2.inRange()?  Then use morphology and or contours to clean up.

Thank you @ChristophRackwitz for the response. Actually, I don't have a constant length of numbers. My model is supposed to predict single-digit, 7-digit, and 8-digit numbers and video frames. This approach came to mind when I trained a model on single digits and segmented the numbers if I got multi-digit numbers and gave them one by one to the model.
Do you think the approach you mentioned here will work for this use case? If so, could you please provide more details on it?

Oh, that works @fmw42. Thank you for sharing this information.
But, this doesn't work on the shadow image which is the first one I shared above, and colored number image.
What should be the approach for incorporating those in this logic as well?

@Cielo You might want to mention the type of inputs that you want to handle. Do you want to handle colored numbers or will they always be in dark color? Is the background consistent? Will images be skewed? The more the variations, the harder it will be to come up with a one-size-fits-all solution.

@Cielo It should work fine for the shadowed image above as the dark letters are darker than the shadow. Choose a more restrictive range for the black letters.  What colored number image?  Please show an example.

I have updated the question above. The images I have include those with shadows and without shadows, numbers written on pieces of paper and on white backgrounds, and colored numbers as well. I have shared the different kinds of images that I will handle in this problem above @GaneshTata

Yes, the method suggested by Christoph Rackwitz is amazing, and it works on shadow and non-shadow images where horizontal lines are present. However, the issue is that I have color numbers on a white background and single-digit MNIST numbers as well. There are separate methods for each of them, but there could be some robust approach that can handle images like those mentioned above.
@fmw42

in the case of that blogspot image you linked below, with clear black digits on plain white background, the morphological closure (to erase the lines on ruled paper, which aren't in this picture) was too strong. without it, the mask result looks fine: https://i.sstatic.net/E4aWorIZ.png and https://i.sstatic.net/pBoWQbef.png

there can be no "universal" algorithm. you'll always encounter examples that break your current logic, and then you'll have to figure out what to change so the new example is covered. for any program you can think of, someone could present a counterexample. that will escalate until the program is generally intelligent. that is the only answer that will satisfy all likely amendments to your question. -- what data are you specifically, actually likely to encounter, and why is that considered data you are expected to operate on?

related question, same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79127410/i-need-to-extract-each-of-the-numbers-from-the-image

To compensate for uneven illumination, a standard technique is to first estimate illumination and then divide.
The background is a white sheet of paper, so that's great. I'll estimate illumination with a median blur. The kernel size must be large enough such that no part of the foreground (written text) remains.
This will also, coincidentally, correct white balance. If the text were colored, it'd still be colored.
im = cv.imread("KifRNuGy.jpg")

illumination = cv.medianBlur(im, 101)

compensated = im / illumination

# arbitrary 0.8 to keep the bright background within range
compensated = (0.8 * 255 * np.clip(compensated, 0, 1)).astype(np.uint8)



For the segmentation, perform morphological "closing". That will erase the fine lines. Now you can get connected components from that, get their bounding boxes, but take the images from the source, because all that will have distorted the handwritten digits.


Or with a fixed 256x256 region:



by the way, a natural way to augment your data would be to draw variously positioned lines over the (line-free) digits. that'll nicely simulate the "debris" expected of handwritten digits on lined/ruled paper. those lines ought to have varying width and intensity, and they should be blended with the digit instead of just drawn over it.

Thank you for sharing this method. That actually works for such images, but if we have image like these:

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fGR7t6RnXZs/Uv5kdmT89_I/AAAAAAAAAjg/zZHfaCqnkak/s1600/freeDrawExport_012314055352.png


but then what happens?

I have updated the question above and added more clarity on the final goal that I am looking for. Thank you so much again for your help here.

in the case of that blogspot image with clear black digits on plain white background, the morphological closure (to erase the lines on ruled paper, which aren't in this picture) was too strong. without it, the mask result looks fine: https://i.sstatic.net/E4aWorIZ.png and https://i.sstatic.net/pBoWQbef.png -- there can be no "universal" algorithm. you'll always encounter examples that break your current logic, and then you'll have to figure out what to change so the new example is covered.

I believe we can solve this with adaptive thresholding. We provide these images, and we segment each number in sequence. I'm not sure how to use it properly. Can you help?
